# How to identify the pressed button in Qt C++?

Tags: c++, qt

I have 4 buttons on my main window. Each button opens its own window with its own data. How to identify the pressed button to open right window? For example: I press sales button and it opens a window that shows information about ticket sales.

[Mainwindow ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLiu3.png)

Here is my code from mainwindow h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <sales.h>
#include <theatres.h>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void button_pressed();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    sales *s;
    theatres *t;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

And here is my code from mainwindow cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "build/sqlite/sqlite3.h"
#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>
#include <QTableView>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect((*ui).pushButton,SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(button_pressed()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{   
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::button_pressed()
{
    
    s = new sales(this);
    s -> show();
}
```

Comment: You should use a different slot for each button. Like `on_btn1clicked()`, `on_btn2clicked()`

Answer (score 1):

As Andy Newman already answered
the shortest solution is a lambda function

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);

QHBoxLayout *h_layout = new QHBoxLayout;

centralWidget()->setLayout(h_layout);

    for(int c =1; c <= 10; c++)
    {
    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(this); // create button

        button->setText(QString::number(c));  // set button id
        h_layout->addWidget(button);    // add a button to the form

        // lambda magic
        /* connecting a button signal to a lambda function that captures a pointer to a
             button and invokes an arbitrary type function. */
        connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, [this, button]() {
            pressedButton(button->text());
        });
    }
}

void MainWindow::pressedButton(const QString &id_button)
{
    qDebug("Pressed button: %ls", id_button.utf16());
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "./ui_widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(ui->btn_0,&QPushButton::clicked,this,&Widget::SlotButtonClicked);
    connect(ui->btn_1,&QPushButton::clicked,this,&Widget::SlotButtonClicked);
    connect(ui->btn_2,&QPushButton::clicked,this,&Widget::SlotButtonClicked);
    connect(ui->btn_3,&QPushButton::clicked,this,&Widget::SlotButtonClicked);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Widget::SlotButtonClicked()
{
    auto sender = this->sender();
    if ( sender == ui->btn_0 ) {
        //  Click btn_0 to open widget0
    } else if ( sender == ui->btn_1 ) {
        //  Click btn_1 to open widget1
    } else if ( sender == ui->btn_2 ) {
        //  Click btn_2 to open widget2
    } else if ( sender == ui->btn_3 ) {
        //  Click btn_3 to open widget3
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a neat implementation!

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this would be to connect the 4 different buttons to 4 different slots. It looks like you are using QtDesigner so that shouldn't be an issue.

If you were generating an array of buttons at run time you'd run into problems and would need a different solution. You could try something like this to pass an array index to the function, for example:

```
connect(button[x], &QPushButton::clicked, this, [this, x]() { button_pressed(x); });
```

Or you could do it the Qt way, which would be to call ::setProperty to store data in the button, and then retrieve it from the event, but it's so esoteric that I can't actually remember how to do that...

Comment: You can still connect the `clicked` signal from the `QPushButton` to any slot in the class/runtime.

Comment: Yes, but if I have an unknown number of buttons I would need an unknown number of slots to receive them all, and I don't _think_ I can create slots at runtime?

Comment: There would be other techniques to achieve that, but it also doesn't have to be an unknown number of buttons. Usually, UI tends to be quite standard. If it were an unknown number of buttons, I really can't think of a scenario where you'd have a wildly different tasks for each button after all.

Comment: Most situations where I'd expect buttons to magically appear at runtime are better suited to a custom list box control, but there are rather a lot of examples - layers in a paint app, javascript buttons in a web page, a halo of HUD controls around units in an RTS game... and yes, they'd not have wildly different tasks, which actually makes them more suitable for being one function with an argument ... more likely I'd chose to have multiple instances of a custom widget and handle the buttons each in their own owner, but there are times ...

Comment: The slot-method can also call `sender()` which returns a pointer to the object that emitted the signal.  There are a number of good reasons *not* to do that (for one, it means your slot-function won't work correctly if it is ever called via any other mechanism), but sometimes it is convenient for a quick-and-dirty implementation.

Comment: The other common method is to connect all your buttons to a `QSignalMapper()` and then listen to its `mapped()` signal.  Though, apparently, this class is now considered obsolete...

Comment: @Andy, shouldn't that be `QObject::setProperty()`, not `::setProperty()`?

Comment: Ah, yes, I wasn't being formal - like I said I can't remember how it works - _something_ has a setProperty function and I assume OP can figure out what :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `Qt Designer`, the best way to do this is to click with button right on the `QPushButton` (On .ui file in Qt Designer) and click to "Go to Slot", this will create a private slot to this button! In the header file will create the definition, like this:

```cpp
private slots:

    void on_pushButton_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_3_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_4_clicked();
```

And in the source file (.cpp) will create the "function" `clicked pushButton`:

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{

}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{

}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_4_clicked()
{

}
```

Inside of the "function" in .cpp, you put the task that you want this button to do, in this case, to open a new window!

When you click "go to slot" in another button, will create another private slot with the respective number (If is the second `QPushButton` that you create, the private slot will be called by `pushButton_2`).